# I can't change administrator password on G5 PPC OS X 10.5.8

Tags: macos, password

I have a problem with my G5 PPC with OS X 10.5.8.
I bought this Mac from an English friend of mine. He forgot an administrator password. I don't have the system CD or Internet connection.

I tried to follow your instructions in other post (command+s) but this is what happens when I do that (on the Mac).

I wrote the command like post and i tried to write in different mode. If you look the last row the command was not found or nothing found to load.

Now i have a new problem. following your instruction this is the results
!

i hope you can help me please step by step ... because i'am desperate

Excuse me for my english

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aClyq.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103953/i-forgot-the-password-to-mac-os-x-10-5-8-leopard-how-can-i-reset-it?rq=1), then from looking at your screen shot it appears that you didn't enter exactly what was specified. For example, there was the command `mount -uw /` but you didn't put the space between the command switches and the slash. Since that didn't execute the mount that you wanted, I'm not surprised the rest of it didn't work :-)

As a side note, though Apple HFS+ installations tend to be case insensitive, it is always possible that case sensitivity is enabled on the computer. As such, you entered the `rm .Applesetupdone` line incorrectly since it should have been `.AppleSetupDone`.

You'll probably have improved luck with the mount statement, but when working with the UNIX shell you should always be case sensitive and careful with spaces, dashes, quotes, etc. since UNIX traditionally is VERY sensitive to these things and the wrong keystroke can render the OS installation non-bootable.